# Xcode 6 localization. export .xliff file will cut the string when the string is like "this is sample \"text\""

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6, xliff

This is the Objective-C code:

```
NSString *text = NSLocalizedString(@"Test \"this is a sample text\"", @"Test \"this is a sample text\"");
```

and this is the result in .xliff file:

[image]

So as you can see, the `id` and `source` is missing. Can any one fix this? Or it is Xcode bug?

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it's an Xcode bug.

Comment: Same here... pretty annoying!

Comment: I have the same problem in Xcode 6. Very annoying.

Comment: I have the same problem with Xcode 6.1 and 6.1.1. I have filed a bug to Apple

Answer (score 2):

It seems Xcode 6.3 fixed this bug.

Comment: Great, they fixed double quotes with Xcode 6.3 but 6.3 [broke apostrophes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29623140/1693173)!?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in the way Xcode handles the `.strings` -> `.xliff` conversions, and so on.  You'll have to wait for Apple to fix it.

May I suggest using curly quotes in the meantime?

`@"Text “this is a sample text”"`

It seems to export to XLIFF properly.