# Error while "Export For Localization.." Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I want to add some new languages to my projects but after clicking `Editor -> Export For Localization -> Save`, I get the following error:

```
Localization failed reading "/var/folders/rs/_qctp1n15gl81l8s0rm7njnh0000gn/T/Xcode3SourceStringsAdaptor-2E68CCA9-A2EA-4EE4-8ED1-A9250721AFC1/Localizable.strings"

Please address the issue at file location 990
```

I have tried it in different projects, some working well some have this error. All projects have the same languages and are already localized I just have to add some other languages.

I have no idea what's the reason or how I can solve this problem.

I am grateful for any response!

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with Xcode 6.3. People are discussing it on the apple dev forums but it doesn't look like there is a solution yet.

Comment: Could you please post a link to the discussion @Casey ?

Comment: I found it myself :D
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1124153#1124153

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue seems to be in Xcode 6.3, that the XLIFF parser suddenly chokes on unescaped quotes ('). A solution seems to be to escape (with a backslash) all instances of quotes in your source code, e.g replace `@"Foobar's" with @"Foobar\'s"`.

Comment: This worked for fixing strings that are in Objective-C but it doesn't help when the string is in a .storyboard.  Is there a workaround for storyboards?

Comment: I found a better workaround.  I replaced the ' (apostrophe) characters with ’ (left single quote) characters in both storyboards and .m files.  That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I suffered enough with this bug :@@@

Comment: Awesome! How did you detect, which character is cause error? for example: "Please address the issue at file location 990" - what 990 means? character #990 in file?

Comment: @progrmr where `’` fyi: `option - shift - ]` on mac. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: This solution is not ideal, since after export and import back localisations - escape sign is gone!

Comment: None of the workarounds seem adequate. My objective-C code does NOT contain any apostrophes. But one of the translations in a Localizable.strings file contains an apostrophe. That alone causes Xcode to fail in the same manner. I was tempted to start replacing apostrophes by single quotes in my English code, but to do that in translated files would be a major problem.  I have filed a radar with Apple.

Comment: @rene I also filed a radar and was told it was a dup.  [Quinn](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1127998#1127998) says it's fixed in an "upcoming version" of Xcode.  We've gone back to [Xcode 6.2](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=6.2) until we see that version.

Comment: @skywinder you can find any character, such as "right single quotation mark", on the Character Viewer (System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Show Keyboard & Character Viewers)

Comment: I have the same problem here. Funny thing is, I don't have any (') in my codes. Probably have to wait for the updates from Xcode team.

Comment: [Xcode 6.3.2 gm](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) released May 8 fixes this problem for me.

Comment: **Beware** of this escape symbol! check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32584732/1698467

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer has an issue: after exporting and import back localisations - escape sign is gone!

As @progrmr mention in comments - there is better workaround to replace `'` with left single quote `’` sign! (<kbd>option</kbd> - <kbd>shift</kbd> - <kbd>]</kbd> on OS X)

Comment: Another solution is to go back to [Xcode 6.2](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode#) and wait for the fixed version of Xcode.

Comment: every version of Xcode has a lot of bugs, you get to choose which ones bother you least

Answer (score 2):

There's an Xcode 6.3.2 GM seed available in the developer portal downloads section. It fixed the problem for our project.

Answer (score 2):

Is fixed in today release of Xcode Version 6.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with XIB/Storyboard files that are localized but don't have any UI element to localize.

Those files happen to generate empty `.strings` files. Those empty `.strings` files cause the parser to throw an error, like the following: `Failed to read strings file, underlying error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.`

Removing the localization for those files worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I play the problem with these steps:

In xcode 6.3:
1. Do a regex search for \@\".*\'.*\" in the whole project.
2. I found no localized string have ', but quite a lot of sting in FMDB source code has SQL comment with '...

So, I Download the xcode 6.2 again, install it and "Export for Localization..." comes back!(spent me half and hour)